# Existe algum método simples para testar um modelo lógico de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Faz pouco tempo que aprendi o Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento, e meu professor me ensinou que após o modelo lógico estar pronto é sempre interessante testar o modelo para verificar possíveis incorreções.

Concordo que isto é bem importante, o problema é a forma de testar. Ele nos ensinou a criar todas as tabelas e povoá-las com dados reais... No Microsoft Word...

Funciona, mas aquilo é um saco, nossa me dá até dor de cabeça...

Expliquei minha situação para uma pessoa experiente, e ele me deu uma sugestão pior ainda: Desenhar todas as tabelas em uma folha de papel e testar manualmente... Sinceramente, já fazem quase 40 anos que o Modelo E-R está aí, pelo amor de Deus né ...

Então, eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta para montas as tabelas com maior facilidade (no word demora demais), ou então se é interessante testar direto no SGBD, e, se este for o caso, quais são os erros pelos quais devo me atentar.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso o brModelo para criar a estrutura lógica,também existe o MySql Workbench que tem um visual bem mais legal que o brModelo,entretanto, eu prefiro o primeiro devido a sua simplicidade.
  Faça uma pesquisa no google de como você pode usar essas ferramentas para ajudar o seu trabalho!! No começo o meu professor pedia para a gente fazer no Word e no papel também!! No começo é assim a pessoa fica um pouco desnorteado, de uma olhada nessas ferramentas!!